# Calculating the possibility of two digits

Tags: algorithm

There are two variables: a and b. a’s initial value is 1, and b is 0. 
There are two buttons: red and blue. Red button adds b’s value to a, and blue button adds a’s value to b.

```
red : a = a+b 
blue: b = b+a
```

Now the problem is if you can get int X on a, and Y on b.

For example, you are given `X = 7, Y=9.`

You start with a=1, b=0. 
Blue button twice will make b `0+1+1=2`, and a remains unchanged.
Then red button can pressed 3 times, `1+2+2+2=7`. 
So `a=7`, `b=2`, then blue button can make b `2+7=9`. Finally, `a=7` and `b=9`.

How would I calculate the possibility of getting X and Y using those two buttons? The algorithm must work on larger digits (>1000)

You dont have to know the path of the buttons to get the digits, but only the possibilities.

Comment: this looks like a hard probability problem that is better suited for [math.exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/). What makes it hard is that the path does matter (2 red, 1 blue is not the same as 1 blue 2 red).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ev. Kounis This problem has no relation to probabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pair `(X, Y)` is possible if `X` is positive, and the greatest common divisor of `X` and `Y` is 1. That's relatively easy to prove:

> First note, that if `X,Y` is possible, then the gcd must be 1. Because
>   otherwise, consider a minimal `X,Y` that's possible with gcd not equal to
>   1. Neither `X` nor `Y` can be 0. But this minimal `X,Y` must have come from a possible `X-Y,Y` or `X,Y-X`, but
>   both of these have the same gcd as `X,Y`, and are smaller, contradicting our assumption
>   of minimality.
>
> Second, suppose there's `X,Y` has gcd equal to 1 (other than `0,1`
>   which is the only pair with `gcd=1` and `X=0`) which is not possible.
>   Consider a minimal such `X,Y`. Then again, this must have come from
>   either `X-Y,Y` or `X,Y-X` which both have `gcd=1`, and again we've got a
>   contradiction from the assumption of minimality.
>
> Thus we've shown that except for `0,1`, then `gcd(X,Y)=1` if and only
>   if `X,Y` is reachable.

Then one can use a standard gcd algorithm to compute the answer:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b > 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def solvxy(X, Y):
    return X>0 and gcd(X, Y)==1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This actually worked, and I didn't think it'd be this easy. But I still don't really get how this works, can you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can unwind (possible) solution from X, Y values.

Subtract smaller value from larger.

In case of tie: for (1,1) solution exists, for larger values - not.

If you reach (1, 0) values - solution does exists

```
X   Y    Sub    
7   9     x 
7   2     y
5   2     y
3   1     y
1   1     both x and y
for x:
1   0    !!! solution found
```

Recursive Python function:

```
def solxy(aa, bb):
    if (aa < 1):
        return False
    if (bb == 0):
        return (aa == 1)
    if (aa == bb):
        return (aa == 1)
    elif (bb > aa):
        return solxy(aa, bb - aa)
    else:
        return solxy(aa - bb, bb)

print(solxy(7,9))
print(solxy(9,7))
print(solxy(3,3))
print(solxy(3,0))
print(solxy(0,3))
print(solxy(1,0))

True
True
False
False
False
True
```

**Edit:**
Iterative solution (uses modulo operation as proposed by @squeamish ossifrage):

```
def solxyit(aa, bb):
    while (aa > 1) and (bb > 1):
        if (bb > aa):
            bb %= aa
        else:
            aa %= bb
    return (aa == 1) or ((bb==1) and (aa>1))
```

Comment: You are right. It is more like a *feasibility* problem. Would be kind enough to edit the question (including the tags, because this is certainly not Python).

Comment: If a<b, then you calculate solxy(a, b-a). You can cut out a lot of steps by replacing this with solxy(b%a, a). Also, if this code needs to work with numbers containing 1000+ digits, an iterative solution would be better than a recursive one (to avoid stack overflow)

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage Yes, I just wanted to show recursive unwinding. Iterative version added. BTW, `a%b` should account for `b=1` (zero remainder)

Comment: I think it's sufficient to return `True` whenever `aa == 1`. The second part of your return statement (`or ((bb==1) and (aa>1))`) looks wrong. For example, if X=2 and Y=1, then the function should return `True` (a=1, b=0; b += a; a += b).

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage Without second part input (9,7) returns false (9,7-2,7-2,1-stop, false), not treating 2,1 properly

Answer (score 0):

```
def two_digits(a, b):
    INIT_A = 1
    INIT_B = 0

    assert ( (type(a) == int or type(a) == long) and (type(b) == int or type(b) == long) )

    #print a, b

    if a == INIT_A and b == INIT_B:
        return True
    if a < INIT_A or b < INIT_B:
        return False

    if a == INIT_A:
        times = (b - INIT_B) / INIT_A;

        #print times, " press b"
        return (times * INIT_A + INIT_B == b)
    elif b == INIT_B:
        return False           #cause a > INIT_A, and INIT_B is 0, thus can't reach(a, INIT_B)
    else:
        if a > b:
            times = (a - INIT_A) / b
            return two_digits(a - times * b, b)
        elif a < b:
            times = (b - INIT_B) / a
            return two_digits(a, b - a * times)
        else:
            return two_digits(0, b) or two_digits(a, 0)

print two_digits(7, 9)
print two_digits(5000, 5003)
```